# How to make a player only be able to jump a certain height in Java?

Tags: java

So, for a school project, I've been trying to get a jumping mechanism down. However, the problem I've been having is that the player is able to just float around, rather than having to fall down after reaching a certain jump height.

I have tried many things, including the normal idea of when the up key is pressed, setting jumping equal to true, and then in the actionPerformed method, setting the yVelocity to -4. But, when the jump key is clicked, I record the yPosition at the time, and when the current yPosition is less than the original position - 50, I set the yVelocity equal to 0, and the fallVelocity to 1.

This is the code in my actionPerformed method:

```
if (jumping) {
            if (yPos <= homeY - 50) {
                yVel = 0;
                fallVel = 1;
                falling = true;
                jumping = false;
                System.out.println("bye");
            }   else {
                yVel = -JUMP_SPEED;
            }
        }
        yPos += yVel + fallVel;
```

'''

This is the code in the keyPressed method:

```
if (!jumping && !falling) {
            jumping = true;
            homeY = yPos;
            count = 0;
        }
```

So, I expect the result to be a player that goes up 50 pixels, and then starts falling down. But in the program, the player just sort of keeps on floating, as long as the up key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Jumping does not really work properly as an up/down switch imo. The best approach is to use gravity (which is very easy to add).

To add gravity just modify the player velocity each tick. This should be run on a fixed time update loop to make consistent gravity at different frame rates:

```
// Play with this number for rate of gravity
player.ySpeed -= 4.9; // Gravity = 9.8m/s^2
```

Then for your jumping just add to the player `ySpeed`. This will create a natural parabolic jump.

```
if (jumpWasPressed) {
    player.ySpeed += 50; // play with this number for jump height
}
```

This approach does assume you have a hotbox for your "ground" object to stop the player from falling through the ground

Comment: For some reason, once I made that change, the player does not even float/jump anymore, but sticks to the ground, until it reaches the edge, where it just falls down really, really fast, and dies. How would I fix that?

Comment: @CrazyComputing that may mean that the jumping is not strong enough, try `player.ySpeed += 1000` and see what effect that has

Comment: @CrazyComputing I can't say much else without seeing the rest of your code